# Disable a button onClick from mapped Card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I Created a card component where I'm mapping thought card and `onClick` to the card I would like to disable the button of the card that I clicked, with my logic it's disabling all the button.

Here is my component where I render the UI

```
renderCard = () => {
const getId = id
const newPoke = pokemon.includes(getId)

  <button disabled={newPoke || this.state.isDisabled}/>
}
```

All component is a card but I removed some code

and here is my render method

```
renderPokemon = () => {
return this.state.pokemon.map(poke => {
return this.renderCard(poke)
  })
}
```

`onClick` to the card I'm making a post request and it's disabling all the cards instead of just the one that I clicked

The state is disabled is changed when i click the post request

Comment: you are not using the poke you are sending to renderCard method

Comment: Yes i do and it's working fine, the cards are rendering, the only problem is when i click on the button it disable all the buttons and not only the one i clicked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `isDisable` should be existed in every `poke` of `this.state.pokemon`.

Hope that helps. Good luck.

I assume that both functions are methods of an component. If It's true. I think you need the component like this.

```
import React from 'react'

interface State {
  pokemon: number[],
  id: number,
  disables: number[]
}
class View extends React.Component<{}, State>{
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      pokemon: [],
      id: Number.NaN,
      disables: []
    }
  }

  renderCard   = () => {
    const getId = this.state.id
    const newPoke = this.state.pokemon.includes(getId)
    const disabled = newPoke || this.state.disables.includes(getId)
    return (
      <button disabled={disabled}></button>
    )
  }
  renderPokemon  = () => {

  }

  render() {
    return this.renderCard()
  }
}

export default View
```

Comment: Not sure how to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

Store the id/ref of the button you wish to disable in the state like:

```
state: {
 disabledButton: ref,
}
```

Then in the callback of the parent pass an onClick handler that receives this ref:

```
handleOnCardClick(ref) {
  this.setState({ disabledButtonRef: ref });
}
```

In each button you can use the hook `useRef` or create a ref if its a stateful component or you can make your own ids for each button although the first is preferable. Then you pass via props the state that holds this ref and compare it in the disabled prop of the card:

```
<Card disabled={disabledButtonRefFromProps === thisCardRef} />
```